# Extracting all the rows in a dataframe that contains a substring from a column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's suppose I have the following two dataframes:

```
int = pd.DataFrame({'domain1':['ABC.6','GF53.7','SDC78.12','GGH7T.64'], 'domain2': ['UI76.89','76TH3.2','YU1QW.45','BY76.12']})

domain1         domain2
ABC.6           UI76.89
GF53.7          76TH3.2
SDC78.12        YU1QW.45
GGH7T.64        BY76.12
```

And another dataframe:

```
doms = pd.DataFrame({'domains':['GF53','VB96','UI76','GGH7T','BY76','ABC','SDC78']})



 domains
    GF53
    VB96
    UI76
    GGH7T
    BY76
    ABC
    SDC78
```

I want to create a new dataframe that will include all the rows from 'int' dataframe only if the values in both 'domain1' and 'domain2' columns contain substrings from 'domain' column in 'doms' dataframe.
For example in this case the result should look like:

```
domain1      domain2
ABC.6        UI76.89
GGH7T.64     BY76.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just some `str.contains` mixed with a joint regex:

```py
int[int.domain1.str.contains('|'.join(doms.domains)) &\
    int.domain2.str.contains('|'.join(doms.domains))]

    domain1  domain2
0     ABC.6  UI76.89
3  GGH7T.64  BY76.12
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) transforms rows to columns then apply contains to filter out the values followed by [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) to get back original data.

```
df[df.stack().str.contains("|".join(doms.domains)).unstack().all(axis=1)]
```

---

```
    domain1  domain2
0     ABC.6  UI76.89
3  GGH7T.64  BY76.12
```